# MongoDB + PHP: How do you query object sizes?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB + PHP: How do you query the size of a document stored in a mongodb object? The document limit, at the time of this writing (recently raised from 4MB), is 16MB.

How can I query the size of a Document using the ObjectId?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.bsonsize(document)` is the function you're after. I'm reading [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/9e66eac1f781763c) and finding a few suggestions about how to do it in php. The easiest is probably to query for the document object and run `strlen` on the `bson_encode`'d object giving you the size in bytes.

```
$byteSize = strlen( bson_encode( $yourDocument ) );
```

If you're wanting to do this check on a lot of documents, say in a loop, without reading back every document you'll need to run a command execute ([Mardix](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=z3iwJxEAAAA19_XwokdR-2YeoPzCNrxekdEasx1kiYTQavV7mdW13Q) had posted this little function to do just that - note: it could easily be rewritten a little better to avoid the hardcoded and global variables):

```
$DBName = "MyDBName"; 
$MongoDB = new MongoDB(new Mongo(),$DBName); 

function documentSize(Array $Criteria){ 
  global $MongoDB; 
  $collectionName = "MyCollection"; 
  $jsonCriteria = json_encode($Criteria); 
  $code = "function(){ 
    return Object.bsonsize(db.{$collectionName}.findOne({$jsonCriteria})) 
  }"; 

  $resp = $MongoDB->execute($code); 
  return $resp["retval"]; 
}
```

PHP example where $id is the document id

```
$myDocSize = documentSize(array("_id"=>$id));
```

Comment: then again, if you're worried about the limit you should be using GridFS.

Comment: how to get multiple documents in a query at once?